# issue with @RequestBody when i pass json

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

When i used **@RequestBody and pass json** from frontend by AJAX with all the parameters of that object it works.

For Ex: @RequestBody Person person
Where person is a bean that contains name and phone info.  So when i pass the json with name and phone info from frontend it works fine.

But it doesnt work when i add another parameter like post_id in json which is not related to person object.  It gives me error stating **"the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()"**

Note : i also added **consumes = "application/json"** and **produces = "application/json"** in spring and in jquery ajax i added **contentType : "application/json"**

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a parameter on the ObjectMapper used by Jackson:

```
objMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

This is one way of setting this in Spring MVC:

Define a Custom Object Mapper this way:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;

public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper(){
        super.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        super.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

}
```

Register this custom ObjectMapper:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven > 
   <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
       <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" >
           <property name="objectMapper">
               <bean class="....CustomObjectMapper"/>
           </property>
       </bean>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Also, in your request you will need to have an "Accept" header of "application/json"

Comment: I have the Jackson Http Message, do think adding a parameter in json which is not in object can cause issue with requestBody ?

Comment: Yes, this is what the javadoc for this parameter says:
> Feature that determines whether encountering of unknown properties (ones that do not map to a property, and there is no "any setter" or handler that can handle it) should result in a failure (by throwing a JsonMappingException) or not. This setting only takes effect after all other handling methods for unknown properties have been tried, and property remains unhandled.

Comment: Where should i put objectMapper configure ?